# Having a formular call a controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I'm having a little issue with learning AngularJS. I'm not 100% sure what are controller about. For exemple, i have the following html div which simply display the result of a SQL request :

```
<div ng-app="searchApp" ng-controller="searchCtrl"> 
<table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names"> 
        <td>{{ x }}</td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And here's the controller :

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('searchApp', []);
app.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope, $http) 
{   
    $http.get("server.php")
    .then(function (response) 
    {
        $scope.result = response.data;
    })
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
});
</script>
```

server.php is returning a simple array of strings, so the page display immediatly a list of names. I would like to add a button on this page, and display this list only AFTER the button has been clicked. I tried to add a form :

```
<div ng-app="searchApp" ng-controller="searchCtrl"> 
<form class="well form-search">
    <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
</form>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in result"> 
        <td>{{ x }}</td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

but this form is calling the search() function, which doesn't exist right now. I would like to call the controller instead.

I don't know if i have made myself very clear, sorry.

Comment: You could put the `$http.get` code in the `search` method of the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//template (no form tag needed)
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="search()">Search</button>

//controller
$scope.search = function(){
 $http.get("server.php")
    .then(function (response) 
    {
        $scope.result = response.data;
    })
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. Still not sure what is $scope ? Is it the html element ?

Comment: hmmm, hard to say in short, check this for example https://www.quora.com/What-is-scope-in-AngularJS-in-laymans-language